# Splunk regex, try to have one group with multiple values

Tags: c#, regex, field, extract, splunk

I have below data coming to Splunk and want to extract.

```
<Data Name="PrivilegeList">SeTcbPrivilege SeSecurityPrivilege SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege SeLoadDriverPrivilege SeBackupPrivilege SeRestorePrivilege SeDebugPrivilege SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege SeEnableDelegationPrivilege SeImpersonatePrivilege</Data>
```

and Regex101, I have this

```
\W\w+\s\w+\W+PrivilegeList\W+(?<Privilege>[A-Za-z0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

right now what I see is

> Group: Privilege = SeTcbPrivilege SeSecurityPrivilege SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege SeLoadDriverPrivilege SeBackupPrivilege SeRestorePrivilege SeDebugPrivilege SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege SeEnableDelegationPrivilege SeImpersonatePrivilege

I want the group of 'Privilege' to have 'single' values of all of those entities.

> For example)
>
> Group: Privilege = SeTcbPrivilege
>
> Group: Privilege = SeSecurityPrivilege
>
> Group: Privilege = SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
>
> Group: Privilege = SeLoadDriverPrivilege
>
> ... so on

I have tried find multiple value but I cannot find examples to follow.

thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to use regex to parse XML?

Comment: just trying to do field extract, I am currently working on props.conf. but a simple question actually, how can i have one group and multiple values. I can do multiple group and multiple values, but not ONE group with many values.

Comment: The regex I provided in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74308787/4418) will still work in `props.conf`. Then you just need to break-up the space-delimited field using `eval` later

Comment: it won't separate each of the list into one group. I can get ALL of them assigned to one group, but not each of the list to the group.

Answer (score 0):

If you *insist* on using a regular expression to parse XML ... this is far simpler:

```
| rex field=_raw "PrivilegeList\"\>(?<privilege>[\w\s]+)"
| eval privilege=split(privilege," ")
```

But... there are better ways to handle XML

Like [`xmlkv`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Xmlkv) or [`xpath`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Xpath)

Comment: Thank you so much! i'll try that from the search. But question, I'm trying to extract field using regex beforehand. which above I've show the example.